# Espacio en blanco al usar column-count / CSS

Tags: html, css

Por CSS estoy añadiendo columnas, necesito que sea un tamaño fijo, por lo que no me sirve utilizar FlexBox.

El problema es que al utilizar column-count se me forma un espacio en blanco entre los div, como pueden ver aquí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo html es el siguiente:

```
 <div class="div-organizacion">
    <div>
        <h2>ORGANIZACIÓN</h2>
        hola
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>RUT ORGANIZACIÓN</h2>
        hola
    </div>
</div>
```

En el CSS lo tengo de esta manera:

```
.div-organizacion{
 column-count: 2;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;}
```

¿Alguna solución? u ¿Otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade una regla deestilo para bajar la segunda columna. Por ejemplo;

```
 .div-organizacion div:nth-child(2){
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:20px;
 }
```

Comment: Gracias, me resulto mejor de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

Te puedes apoyar de la propiedad [*`grid-column-gap`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap), la cual es aplicable para:

- Elementos multi columna
- Contenedores grid
- Contenedores flex

Dando un valor de 0 podrás eliminar el espacio entre las columnas generadas.

Te dejo este ejemplo:

```html
    <style>
    
      .div-organizacion {
        border: 1px solid;
        column-count: 2;
        grid-column-gap: 0;
      }
      .clase {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="div-organizacion">
        <div class="clase">
            <h2>ORGANIZACIÓN</h2>
            hola
        </div>
        <div class="clase">
            <h2>ORGANIZACIÓN</h2>
            hola
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aunque también lo puedes manejar con la sintaxis de [*column-gap*](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_column-gap_multicol_context) y debería funcionarte, pero personalmente me apegaría a la sintaxis de MDN.